# Parameter count mismatch. - Threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am trying to create a multi-client / server chat small application using WPF but I have some problems. Unfortunately when I press the Connect button the program crashes.

Well, I done that so far with the client program(with the thread): 
`public delegate void UpdateText(object txt);`

I got that method:

```
    private void UpdateTextBox(object txt)
    {
        if (msg_log.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateText(UpdateTextBox),txt);

        }
        else
        {
            msg_log.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateText(UpdateTextBox), txt);
        }
    }
```

And I am using a Button_Click event to connect to the server like that:

```
        private void connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        if ((nick_name.Text == "") || (ip_addr.Text == "") || (port.Text == ""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nick name, IP Address and Port fields cannot be null.");
        }
        else
        {

            client = new Client();
            client.ClientName = nick_name.Text;
            client.ServerIp = ip_addr.Text;
            client.ServerPort = port.Text;
            Thread changer = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(UpdateTextBox));
            changer.Start();
            client.OnClientConnected += new OnClientConnectedDelegate(client_OnClientConnected);
            client.OnClientConnecting += new OnClientConnectingDelegate(client_OnClientConnecting);
            client.OnClientDisconnected += new OnClientDisconnectedDelegate(client_OnClientDisconnected);
            client.OnClientError += new OnClientErrorDelegate(client_OnClientError);
            client.OnClientFileSending += new OnClientFileSendingDelegate(client_OnClientFileSending);
            client.OnDataReceived += new OnClientReceivedDelegate(client_OnDataReceived);
            client.Connect();

        }
    }
```

Please note that the OnClient* events are like `private void client_OnDataReceived(object Sender, ClientReceivedArguments R) { UpdateTextBox(R.ReceivedData); }`

So these events should write some text like "Connected" into the msg_log TextBox

PS. The txt object used to be a string variable but I change it since `ParameterizedThreadStart` only accepts objects as parameters as I know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
George

EDIT: Edited the UpdateTextBox method as Abe Heidebrecht suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your `Invoke` calls.

- You don't need to create an object array to pass the parameters.
- Passing `DispatcherPriority.Normal` is redundant (`Normal` is default).
- You aren't passing any parameters to the second `Invoke` method (which is probably where your error is happening).

It should look like this:

```
private void UpdateTextBox(object txt)
{
    if (msg_log.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateText(UpdateTextBox), txt);
    }
    else
    {
        msg_log.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateText(UpdateTextBox), txt);
    }
}
```

**EDIT For `StackOverflowException`**

This will cause a `StackOverflowException` because you are calling your method in an infinite loop. This is happening because your method is simply calling itself over and over again.

What `Dispatcher.Invoke` does is invoke the passed delegate on the thread that owns the `Dispatcher`. Just because the `msg_log` may have a different dispatcher, when you were calling `UpdateTextBox`, you were passing a delegate to the current method, which causes the infinite loop.

What you really need to do is call a method on the msg_log object, like so:

```
private void UpdateTextBox(object txt)
{
    if (msg_log.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        if (txt != null)
            msg_log.Text = txt.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        msg_log.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateText(UpdateTextBox), txt);
    }
}
```

Comment: First thank you for your quick reply.
Well, now that error seems to be solved but now another error message is coming up when I press the Connect Button. _An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll_ 

Please note that the OnClient* events are like 

`        private void client_OnDataReceived(object Sender, ClientReceivedArguments R)
        {
            UpdateTextBox(R.ReceivedData);
        }
`


So these events should write some text like "Connected" into the msg_log TextBox

Comment: @GeorgeChondrompilas A stack overflow suggests that you've got a recursive loop going on.  I.e. whatever changes your invoked method is doing is causing `UpdateTextBox` to trigger again, causing more changes, causing more triggers, etc.

Comment: @GeorgeChondrompilas I have updated the answer to address this.

Comment: @AbeHeidebrecht Thanks but that does not seem to work. System.Windows.Controls.TextBox does not contain UpdateTextBox method.

Comment: @GeorgeChondrompilas Okay, I thought your msg_log was a custom class that you implemented. I've updated the answer to set the msg_log.Text property.

Comment: @AbeHeidebrecht Yep that's working, Thank you so much. One more thing, my msg_log is a multiline text box. I want each time the method is called, a new string should be placed under the last one. That's why I created an object array. Any suggestions?

Comment: @GeorgeChondrompilas Instead of setting the text value, append the new text with a newline: `msg_log.Text += Environment.NewLine + obj.ToString();`

Comment: @AbeHeidebrecht Okay, now it's working perfectly. Thank you once again. I really appreciate it. EDIT: I prefer:
`msg_log.Text +=  txt.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;` because your suggestion always leave the first line blank.